# How do I create a smooth scroll to element of a given id, within a modal, WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript, scroll, modal-dialog

So I have code for a onclick event, that will cause a  smooth scroll in plain (no jquery) Javascript to an element of a given id, now I want to implement it within a modal.

```
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
  if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
    if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
    scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}


 elmnt = document.getElementById("example");
 scrollTo(document.body, elmnt.offsetTop, 600);
```

For an element with id = "example".
I have a modal with id = "myModal" with CSS property overflow-y : scroll, and when a click event triggers, I would like the modal to scroll smoothly to an element of id = "poleTimeDiv".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

just so we all know, this does the trick.

CSS

```
.scrollable-content {
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
}
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector('poleTimeDiv').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Comment: scroll-behavior: smooth is not supported in Safari

Answer (score 0):

Take a look,there is a native CSS feature for this: `scroll-behavior`.

**CSS**

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' <pre rel="HTML"><code markup="tt" class="language-markup">
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll to a certain element
document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: I found the solution via that link, so thank you. I couldn't get the above to work but got there eventually.

Answer (score -1):

Using the smooth scroll library no Jquery

```css
body {

height: 700px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll@14.0.0/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>

<a data-scroll href="#bazinga">Click here</a>
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div id="bazinga">Bazinga!</div>

<script>
 var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
    speed: 500,
   speedAsDuration: true
  });
</script>
```